# Sentry installed via docker - how to set up https?

Tags: docker, https, sentry

I've set up [sentry in docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/sentry/).

Run it with `docker run -d -i -t -p 8080:9000 --restart=always --name pb-sentry -e SENTRY_SECRET_KEY='key' --link sentry-redis:redis --link sentry-postgres:postgres --link sentry-smtp:smtp sentry`. It works on 8080 port ok.

But I need to make it available via HTTPS. How?

Comment: Is your problem resolved? I am also trying same thing with apache

Answer (score 4):

You may use a proxy server such as **nginx** and forward `443` (https) to `8080` -if sentry does not supports directly- You may even use your own ssl certs with nginx easily and provide higher security.

If it supports directly check their docs.

Comment: I keep seeing use of nginx for setting up ssl for Sentry. Could explain why nginx is so commonly used and whether it is required or not? Can't I simply set the SSL variables in sentry (which I haven't managed to make work so far). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SemihSezer, nginx is a web server. It is a dedicated web server and has tons of abilities. Do you need nginx with sentry? No. But let's say you have 2 apps in same server and both apps need to be served from port `80`. Now, you can run those applications on different ports and use nginx as a proxy server so that you can open them without giving any port in the url. That's basically why most people using it. Even, setting those ssl parameters are much more easy and flexible on nginx.

Answer (score 4):

I got this working by setting up UWSGI's HTTPS support: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HTTPS.html

I configured Sentry to use it with the following in the `sentry.conf.py` file.

```
SENTRY_WEB_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
SENTRY_WEB_PORT = '9000,sentry.crt,sentry.key'
SENTRY_WEB_OPTIONS = {
    'protocol': 'https'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I configure sentry docker-compose file by adding nginx-ssl service in the docker-compose using `valian/docker-nginx-auto-ssl` docker image.
I also modify the nginx service:

```yaml
...
  nginx:
    <<: *restart_policy
#    ports:
#      - "$SENTRY_BIND:80/tcp"
    image: "nginx:1.21.0-alpine"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        read_only: true
        source: ./nginx
        target: /etc/nginx
    depends_on:
      - web
      - relay
  nginx-ssl:
    <<: *restart_policy
    image: valian/docker-nginx-auto-ssl
#    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    volumes:
      - ssl_data:/etc/resty-auto-ssl
    environment:
      ALLOWED_DOMAINS: 'sentry.example.com'
      SITES: 'sentry.example.com=nginx:80'
...
volumes:
  ...
  ssl_data:
...
```